# AngularJS, inconsistencies when assigning versus updating scope within the transcluded content of a directive's isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**JSBin Example**:
http://jsbin.com/yuyetakonowu/1/edit?html,js,output

**Summary**:
I have two directive's (myParentDirective and myChildDirective). myParentDirective transcludes myChildDirective content. I am attempting to two-way-bind a model object within myChildDirective. It works successfully when I "update" the object by simply changing or adding properties to an existing object instance. However, when I "assign" a new object (using equals operator from the controller's timeout function) myChildDirective will not be updated.

**HTML**:

```
<html ng-app='ValidationApp'>

<head>
    <title>Assigning a model object after isolated scope is set doesn't work</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller='MyController'>

    <h2>MyController.assignedObject: {{assignedObject}}</h2>
    <h2>MyController.updatedObject: {{updatedObject}}</h2>

    <my-parent-directive assigned-object='assignedObject' updated-object='updatedObject'>
        <my-child-directive></my-child-directive>
    </my-parent-directive>


    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var app = angular.module('ValidationApp', [])

app.controller('MyController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        // Model objects loaded on page-load
        $scope.assignedObject = {value: 'pre-update'}
        $scope.updatedObject = {value: 'pre-update'}

        // Mock ajax request
        setTimeout(function() {

            // This is what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish. However, myChildDirective is not properly
            // showing the updated value 'post-update'.
            $scope.assignedObject = {value: "post-update"}

            // I noticed that this line will properly update myChildDirective, but it's not an ideal solution.
            // I'm including it in the example just to show the inconsistent results in myChildDirective.
            $scope.updatedObject.value = "post-update"

            $scope.$apply()

        }, 1000)
    }
])

app.directive('myParentDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            assignedObject: '=',
            updatedObject: '='
        },
        template: '\
            <h2>myParentDirective.assignedObject: {{assignedObject}}</h2>\
            <h2>myParentDirective.updatedObject: {{updatedObject}}</h2>\
            <div ng-transclude></div>\
            ',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            this.assignedObject = $scope.assignedObject
            this.updatedObject = $scope.updatedObject
        }
    }
})

app.directive('myChildDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^myParentDirective',
        scope: false,
        template: '\
            <h2>myChildDirective.myParentDirective.assignedObject: {{myParentDirective.assignedObject}}</h2>\
            <h2>myChildDirective.myParentDirective.updatedObject: {{myParentDirective.updatedObject}}</h2>\
            ',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, myParentDirective) {
            $scope.myParentDirective = myParentDirective
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a few solutions to my problem...

The problem is that I'm assigning $scope.assignedObject to this.assignedObject within myParentDirective. When I do this, there's no way for myChildDirective to know when the property has changed. Ordinarily, $scope.$apply() function would be called to notify all observers that a scope property has changed, but since I'm re-assigning this object reference to this.assignedObject myChildDirective never receives that event.

The simplest solution can be found here: http://jsbin.com/yuyetakonowu/11/edit. Basically, this is simply inheriting the parent scope so that I can rely on angular's scope to emit the appropriate event and update myChildDirective accordingly.

However, this wasn't good enough for me as I also needed myChildDirective to have an isolated scope with its own properties. This means I can't simply "inherit" the parent scope. I've resolved this issue with the following: http://jsbin.com/yuyetakonowu/9/edit.

The end result:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app='ValidationApp'>

<head>
    <title>Assigning a model object after isolated scope is set doesn't work</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller='MyController'>

    <h1>MyController</h1>
    <h2>assignedObject: {{assignedObject}}</h2>
    <h2>updatedObject: {{updatedObject}}</h2>

    <my-parent-directive assigned-object='assignedObject' updated-object='updatedObject'>
        <my-child-directive child-property='child-property-value'></my-child-directive>
    </my-parent-directive>


    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('ValidationApp', [])

app.controller('MyController', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        // Model objects loaded on page-load
        $scope.assignedObject = {value: 'pre-update'}
        $scope.updatedObject = {value: 'pre-update'}

        // Mock ajax request
        setTimeout(function() {

            // This is what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish. However, myChildDirective is not properly
            // showing the updated value 'post-update'.
            $scope.assignedObject = {value: "post-update"}

            // I noticed that this line will properly update myChildDirective, but it's not an ideal solution.
            // I'm including it in the example just to show the inconsistent results in myChildDirective.
            $scope.updatedObject.value = "post-update"

            $scope.$apply()

        }, 1000)
    }
])

app.directive('myParentDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            assignedObject: '=',
            updatedObject: '='
        },
        template: '\
            <h1>myParentDirective</h1>\
            <h2>assignedObject: {{assignedObject}}</h2>\
            <h2>updatedObject: {{updatedObject}}</h2>\
            <div ng-transclude></div>\
            ',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            // Generally, exposing isolate scope is considered bad practice. However, this directive is intended
            // to be used with child directives which explicitly depend on this directive. In addition, child
            // directives will likely need their own isolated scope with two-way binding of properties on this scope.
            this._scope = $scope
        }
    }
})

app.directive('myChildDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^myParentDirective',
        scope: {
            childProperty: '@'
        },
        template: '\
            <h1>myChildDirective</h1>\
            <h2>childProperty: {{childProperty}}</h2>\
            <h2>assignedObject: {{assignedObject}}</h2>\
            <h2>updatedObject: {{updatedObject}}</h2>\
            ',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, myParentDirective) {
            myParentDirective._scope.$watch('assignedObject', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.assignedObject = newValue
            })
            myParentDirective._scope.$watch('updatedObject', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.updatedObject = newValue
            })
        }
    }
})
```